# Finish an already destroyed activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.go)
    public void btnClick() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));

    }
}
```

-

```
public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity implements TestAsyncTask.Callbacks{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn)
    public void onClick() {
        new TestAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(String result) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

-

```
public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<Callbacks> mCallbacks;

    public TestAsyncTask(Callbacks callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = new WeakReference<Callbacks>(callbacks);
    }

    public interface Callbacks {
        void onResult(String result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "WOW";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Callbacks callbacks = mCallbacks.get();
        if(callbacks != null) {
            callbacks.onResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity starts SecondActivity. SecondActivity start an AsyncTask which calls back onResult after ten seconds. If I rotate screen between the callback and starting the asynctask, a new SecondActivity is created. So onResult wiil be called on the old SecondActivity. But why finish() finishes the new one?

I know it's bad to write such code. The asynctask should be cancelled or something. But it's interesting why that happens. Is it an undefined behaviour?

If you'd like to reproduce that consider cloning https://github.com/guliash/AndroidExplorer/tree/test

Comment: the task still has a reference to the activity via that callback. if you dont want that to fire set the callback to null when the device rotates

Comment: I know. But the question is not about how to fix the problem. It is about why finish() kills the new activity.

Comment: what is new activity is it SecondActivity?

Comment: Actually finish call every time when SecondActivity created so when you rotate the screen the finish of new activity getting called and finishes the same activity i.e. new SecondActivity.

Comment: Amy, new activity is an instance of SecondActivity which is created  when i rotate screen.